Export Azure\Entra Group Members with their last sign in date
I'm looking for a script to export members of a Azure\Entra group containing their Display Name, Job Title and Last Sign In Date. Obtaining the Display Name and Job Title seems fairly straight forward but I'm struggling on the lsat sign in date.
Everything I've read suggests Graph is the way forward but I can't seem to find the correct search criteria. Can anyone help me please?
Many thanks,
A

Do you have admin rights to run this command- Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "User.Read.All", "GroupMember.Read.All", "AuditLog.Read.All" ? If yes, then I can share with you a script.

Hi @Arko I do have these permissions yes :) if you could, that would be amazing.

Are you looking for particular group or whole groups of your tenant?

Initially, I created one group and added more than 100 members to it:


# Define the Group IDd
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes Directory.Read.All,AuditLog.Read.All

$groupId = "YOUR GROUP ID"
$groupMembers = Get-MgGroupMember -GroupId $groupId -Top "999"

 $userDetails = $groupMembers | ForEach-Object {
    Get-MgUser -UserId $_.Id -Property 'UserPrincipalName','SignInActivity','Mail','DisplayName','JobTitle'
}
$userDetails | Select-Object @{
    N = 'UserPrincipalName'
    E = { $_.UserPrincipalName }
}, @{
    N = 'DisplayName'
    E = { $_.DisplayName }
}, @{
    N = 'Mail'
    E = { $_.Mail }
}, @{
    N = 'LastSignInDate'
    E = { $_.SignInActivity.LastSignInDateTime }
} | Export-Csv -Path <FilePath> -NoTypeInformation -NoClobber



Output:


Hey @Pratik Jadhav, this is great thank you. I had to switch the Mail filter that was in there for Job Title. Is there a way I can retrieve more than 100 results? Thanks

You want to replace Job Title with Mail ?

To increase the page size add $top parameter with till how much numbers do you want to retrieve for eg.$top=300

@Admaine Updated the answer!

thanks very much. Is it possible to only check for Office 365 Shell WCSS-Client or OfficeHome sign ins and exclude Windows Sign In? Thanks again

sorry didn't tag you
